# Installing @types/jquery results in an unwanted global $ declaration

Tags: jquery, typescript

I have the following defined in `package.json`:

```json
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/jquery": "^3.5.5",
  }
}
```

Which adds the following type declaration via `@types/jquery/misc.d.ts`:

```js
declare const jQuery: JQueryStatic;
declare const $: JQueryStatic;
```

Now I have global `$` and `jQuery` variables defined for all of my modules, but this is not only unwanted... it's wrong. Code similar to the following is blowing up at runtime because the TypeScript compiler believes that `$` is a global when in fact it *must* be imported:

```js
// $ is never imported here, and jQuery is not initialized globally in the browser

export function foo(node?:JQueryXML):void {
    node.children().each(function(_, el) {
        let node = $(el);
        if (node.attr("type") === VALUE) {
            doStuff();
        }
    });
}
```

Just to be sure, I tried commenting out those two declaration lines in `@types/jquery/misc.d.ts` and I got the expected error:

```
error TS2592: Cannot find name '$'. Do you need to install type definitions for jQuery? Try `npm i --save-dev @types/jquery` and then add 'jquery' to the types field in your tsconfig.

40    let node = $(el);
```

However, I've now effectively disabled all jQuery type checking. I've got an additional 50+ errors because all other modules where I correctly import `$` are treating the variable as `any`.

How can I tell the TypeScript compiler that I want the type definitions from `@types/jquery` but that `$` is ***not*** a valid global variable?

Comment: This is very annoying indeed. My project uses jQuery 1 and we can't upgrade it because plugins, but we import jQuery 3 in some places. For typescript, everything is v3, which makes it even more confusing than it is already.

Answer (score 1):

You can explicitly tell TypeScript the `types` to search in the compiler options: https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#types

From the docs:

> By default all visible ”@types” packages are included in your compilation. Packages in node_modules/@types of any enclosing folder are considered visible. For example, that means packages within ./node_modules/@types/, ../node_modules/@types/, ../../node_modules/@types/, and so on.
>
> If types is specified, only packages listed will be included in the global scope.

In this case the compiler is automatically including the global type from `node_modules/@types/jquery`.

Comment: Aside from the fact that I still need jQuery types, I tried your suggestion with the following configuration: `{ "compilerOptions": { "types": [ "moment" ] } }` and TypeScript is still compiling without any errors. If I comment out those to constant declarations in misc.d.ts then I get an error, so I know that the file is being compiled by TypeScript. I really need a reliable way to disable those globals (`$` & `jQuery`) without sacrificing all the useful type information.

Comment: I've added additional details to my question.

Comment: If you removed it from `types` but the type is still there it may be the case of a source file that still includes the global jQuery. Try with `tsc --traceResolution` the output will be very verbose but it may help to find what's going on.

Comment: Note: `types` indicates types to automatically include, but you may still include the types by using an `import`, you can use `import $ from 'jquery'`. If a source file uses `import 'jquery'' it will include the globals as well.

Comment: I've tried running with `--traceResolution`, but I admit that I'm a little confused. I already know that jQuery is imported by other modules in my bundle. The issue is that I forgot to import it in this particular module but the linter didn't detect that, so at runtime `$` was undefined. `@types/jquery` appears to declare a global `$`, but my webpack configuration does not resolve a global `$`. I need TypeScript to catch these sorts of errors in the future, but I can't get it to flag a missing `import $ from "jquery"`

Comment: I don't know how the jQuery TS types are defined as I used jQuery like 10yrs ago. However, I had a similar issue with the NodeJS global types. Sadly it maybe a problem on how the jQuery types are defined. At the beginning of the compilation TSC will scan for imports to resolve types, you can turn that off with the flag `--noResolve`. In that case it will only resolve local imports (and it will give you tons of errors). During the resolution phase TSC imports the req type def, if the definition is global.. you'll have it on the scope :( Perhaps there is an alternative @types/jquery

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the help.